# I couldn't visualize data in d3

Tags: sql, d3.js

I am learning D3, and trying to load data from a database and visualize it on the HTML page.

**My code in PHP:**

```
$myquery = "SELECT COUNT(JOB) FROM EMP WHERE JOB = 'SALESMAN'";

$query = mysqli_query($conn,$myquery);

if ( ! $query ) {
    echo mysqli_error($myquery);
    die;
}

$data = array();

for ($x = 0; $x < mysqli_num_rows($query); $x++) {
    $data[] = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
}

echo json_encode($data);  

mysqli_close($conn);
```

*The data I got:*

```
[{"COUNT(JOB)":"4"}]
```

**My code in HTML:**

```
<script>
    
        d3.json("connect.php",function (data) {
        
            var canvas = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                .attr("width", 500)
                .attr("height", 500)
                
            canvas.selectAll("rect")
                .data(data)
                .enter()
                    .append("rect")
                    .attr("width", function(d){ return d.COUNT(JOB) * 100;})
                    .attr("height",48)
                    .attr("y", function (d, i){ return i * 50;})
                    .attr("fill", "black")
        
        })
    
</script>
```

I thought the problem might be the JSON data, where '4' is a string but not a number. So I changed the data source [{"COUNT(JOB)": "4"}] to [{"COUNT(JOB)":4}]. However, in the HTML page, the bar chart is still not showing. I think the problem should be the javascript. I check every single word, but could not find any problem.

By the way. if I load the data from connect.php, how can I convert the string  '4' into the number 4?

Comment: If you are only starting to learn PHP then you should learn PDO instead of mysqli. PDO is much easier and more suitable for beginners. Start here https://phpdelusions.net/pdo & https://websitebeaver.com/php-pdo-prepared-statements-to-prevent-sql-injection

Comment: You need `.data(data)` instead of `.attr(data)`

Comment: I check it and correct it now. However, it still cannot work.

Comment: Try a `console.log(data)` before `var canvas = ... ` - do you see your data ?

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON will cause you problems with a property name of `COUNT(JOB)`. Here:

```
 function(d){ return d.COUNT(JOB) * 100;})
```

Here you are passing `JOB` to a function `d.COUNT`, except `d.COUNT` is not a function or a property of your datum. This will generate an error and result in nothing being drawn. Instead, you could call your count something like:

```
 SELECT COUNT(JOB) as jobcount ...
```

And access it with `d.jobcount`

---

Secondly, if you are using d3v5 or d3v6 then you are using d3.json incorrectly. The pattern you have used is valid for d3v4  and earlier, but as of d3v5 you'll need to use the following format:

```
 d3.json("connect.php").then(function (data) {

    ...

 })
```

Otherwise, your javascript works: here's a working example of the javascript (hard coding in the data to fit it in a snippet):

```js
var data = [{"jobcount":"4"}]

            var canvas = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                .attr("width", 500)
                .attr("height", 500)
                
            canvas.selectAll("rect")
                .data(data)
                .enter()
                    .append("rect")
                    .attr("width", function(d){ return d.jobcount * 100;})
                    .attr("height",48)
                    .attr("y", function (d, i){ return i * 50;})
                    .attr("fill", "black")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

---

Lastly, in this case you do not need to coerce the string `"4"` to a number, as you can see above (javascript treats it as a number when multiplying it against a number). If you really want to force the value to a number, you can use the unary `+`, eg:

```
`data.forEach(function(d) { d.jobcount = +d.jobcount })`
```

or

```
.attr("width", function(d) { return +d.jobcount; })
```

Comment: Thank you very much for that. I got it run finally haha. I don’t have enough reputation so I cannot vote. But your answer is very very helpful!